# Using Swift array.count and arc4random()

Tags: swift

What am I missing to get this code to work? nodesLeft is an [Int].

```
let x = nodesLeft.count
let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))
```

I get an error:

Playground execution failed: error: :136:40: error: 'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'UInt32'
        let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))

Comment: Guessing that `x` is inferred to be an NSNumber, and arc4random_uniform requires a UInt32, so you need to cast `x` to UInt32.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've encountered the same problems with `arc4random_uniform()`; its argument must be a `UInt32` so cast `x` as such:

```
let x = UInt32(nodesLeft.count)
let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have to cast x in `UInt32`

```
    var nodesLeft = ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"]

    let x = UInt32(nodesLeft.count)
    println(x)

    let r = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))
    println(r)
```